# SCIM User create defaults for Timezone and EmailEncoding

Tags: user-management, identity, cross-domain

If i create a user using the SCIM Rest APIs and don't populate timezone, it defaults to Pacific time.

Since email encoding isn't a supported value in the schema, it always defaults to UTF-8.

Does anyone know how/where the values for these defaults are populated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the time zone by defiining it in the input JSON as  "TimeZone" : "Asia/Kolkata" based on the timezone you wish to set.

Check https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_supported_timezone.htm&type=0 for all the supported values.

I am not aware of setting the email encoding value though.

Comment: As far as i could find out, setting the email encoding isn't part of the schema so it isn't supported.  But spot on answer for timezone. Thank you